# I want to attach some hooks inside my car

Tags: diy, plastic

Want to:

attach some hooks on the inside of my car, so I can hang stuff on them.

The problem:

The inside of my car consists of hard plastic panels. But when I try to get a screw in them, it gets lose very quickly because of the thickness of the material.

Glue is another option, but that seems so permanent. If I should ever want to remove the hook again, then it can be

The question:

How do you attach "stuff" to the plastic panels?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what is behind the panels, a bolt with wide washers could be all you need.

I'd probably go down the glue route myself, or possibly even fix velcro tabs to the plastic with velcro-backed hooks, but if you are wanting to hang things from them, you'll want them to be solid and either way will leave marks if you ever do decide to remove them.

Answer (score 3):

Use something like 3M Command Utility Hooks.  They stick on but can be removed without leaving any sticky adhesive behind.

I would not hang anything more substantial than that from a plastic interior panel because those panels are usually just held on by trim clips that cannot take much weight in the first place.

Comment: The first tip looks like a very good alternative solution, and the second tip is something I would no doubt have found out the hard way. So thanks for that :)